# Make text based predictions

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, text, scikit-learn

My code can make numerical predictions decently but how would I make text-based predictions

I have tried making a python script that turns strings into numbers but it is very inefficient i'm trying to find a better way of doing this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")

data = data[["index1", "index2", "index3", "index4", "index5", "index6"]]

predict = "index6"

X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(data[predict])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test =         
sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
print(acc)

print('Coefficient: \n', linear.coef_)
print('Intercept: \n', linear.intercept_)

predictions = linear.predict(x_test)

for x in range(len(predictions)):
    print(predictions[x], x_test[x], y_test[x])
```

This is the code for numerical predictions.

Comment: what is your code so far for turning strings into numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try vectorizing your words using the [TF-IDF method](https://towardsdatascience.com/tfidf-for-piece-of-text-in-python-43feccaa74f8), this turns strings into arrays of float values, based on their frequency and use. This is the most common method of turning words into numbers for natural language processing, and may work for you as well. There are many [tutorials](https://towardsdatascience.com/tfidf-for-piece-of-text-in-python-43feccaa74f8) regarding TF-IDF vectorizing.